# pass an array to a paint component class?

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing, paintcomponent

I have another beginner's question that hopefully someone can help with.

I'm trying to pass an array from one class to another in order to use it to produce a bar graph. I know I can pass an array as a parameter but I'm getting some errors and am basically a bit lost.
The basic code for the classes for the chart are below. Supposing I want to pass "anArray" from "AnotherClass", can anyone tell me exactly how I should pass it?

I've tried passing it as a parameter of JBChart & chartComponent but I think I need it to be in paintComponent? As it already has "Graphics g" as parameter, I am rather confused. Anyway, either of those two and I get nullPointer errors (although I know I could be doing something else wrong too).

### Here's the basic code for the chart classes. Any ideas very much appreciated:

```
public class JBChart extends JFrame {

    public JBChart()    {}

    public void buildChart()
    {   
        ChartComponent component = new ChartComponent();
        chartFrame.add(component);                           
        chartFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
public class ChartComponent extends JComponent {
    public ChartComponent() {}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    }
```

--

### -EDIT-

This is the first few lines of one of the stack traces (I hope that's enough?): --

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at ChartComponent.<init>(ChartComponent.java:43) at JBChart.<init>(JBChart.java:32) 
at JavaBallGUI.displayBarChart(JavaBallGUI.java:273) 
at JavaBallGUI.actionPerformed(JavaBallGUI.java:310)
```

-- 
The line it points to is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < teamObjects.length; i++) 
{ 
    if (teamObjects[i] != null) 
    { 
    teamName = teamObjects[i].getTeamName(); 
    System.out.println(teamName); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you get exceptions, post the stacktrace and the part of the code mentioned in the stacktrace

Comment: Thanks Robin. This is the first few lines of one of them (I hope that's enough?):
--
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ChartComponent.<init>(ChartComponent.java:43)
 at JBChart.<init>(JBChart.java:32)
 at JavaBallGUI.displayBarChart(JavaBallGUI.java:273)
 at JavaBallGUI.actionPerformed(JavaBallGUI.java:310)
--
The line it points to is:
  for (int i = 0; i < teamObjects.length; i++)
  {
   if (teamObjects[i] != null)
   {
    teamName = teamObjects[i].getTeamName();
    System.out.println(teamName);
   }
  }

Comment: the stacktrace you posted reveals a `NullPointerException` in the constructor of your `ChartComponent` class (line 43). However, in the code you posted in your question is empty. From the code you posted in your comment there is only 1 possible object null and that is the `teamObjects` object. Where is that object coming from. According to your question, I guess you want to pass that `teamObjects` array to your class. How to achieve that is already explained by Jon Skeet

Comment: @Robert: you don't want to post code in a comment since as you can see it is unreadable. Instead, edit your answer, and then in your comment notify others (here you'll want to notify Robin with an `@Robin`) of your edit.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried to edit the original post now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably pass it to the *constructor*:

```
public class ChartComponent extends JComponent {
    private final int[] values; // For example

    public ChartComponent(int[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    }
}
```

Note that this will still allow *either* class to change the values within the array afterwards, as they've both got a reference to the same mutable object. There are various ways round this, depending on exactly what you're trying to do. You'd then use:

```
ChartComponent component = new ChartComponent(array);
```

Alternatively, you could always create setter methods on the `ChartComponent` and call those at the appropriate time. You *won't* be able to change the signature of `paintComponent` and still get the behaviour you want, so you'll need to provide the data before the method is called.

Comment: Thanks Jon. It's an array of objects of type "Team", so would it be something like:
private Team[] teamObjects;
public ChartComponent(Team[] teamObjects)
{
  this.teamObjects = teamObjects;
}

Comment: @Robert: Yes - although I'd make it final, too.

Comment: Hi Jon, in the method where I'm building the array, I'm trying to pass it like this:
--
 ChartComponent(sortedTeams);
--
 and my IDE is telling me the method is undefined?
(I hope that makes sense)

Comment: @Robert: You need `new` to tell it you're calling a constructor.

Comment: I now have:
ChartComponent chart = new ChartComponent(sortedTeams);
still getting a null pointer exception though.

Comment: @Robert: Hard to say what's going wrong only from that description, I'm afraid. Debug into it and check that `sortedTeams` isn't null.